# Why shouldn't one use Neosporin more than three times per day?

Tags: dermatology, wound, dosage, neosporin

https://www.neosporin.com/wound-care/frequently-asked-questions says:

> Treat: Apply a small amount of this product (an amount equal to the surface area of a tip of a finger) on the area 1 to 3 times daily.

Why shouldn't one use Neosporin more than three times per day?